# Localized values of ActionMessage in ValidatorForm

Tags: java, localization, struts, struts-1

I have localized messages, for example:

```
error.message = Invalid {0}
object.foo = Foo
```

and some validation code within my `ValidatorForm`:

`errors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage("errors.message", "Foo"));`

This works just fine. But I want to localize the message arguments as well  using key `object.foo`.

I've tried:

`getServlet().getInternal().getMessage("object.foo");`

but this results in null. Is there some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not so difficult, I'll try find harder next time...

`org.apache.struts.validator.Resources.getMessage(request,key);`